# write loop to get new rows and append to old rows in a data set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a query to an api which has a limit of displaying 1000 rows / request. I can view more rows by adding a query parameter to the string to see next 1000. But it does not show 2000 rows together

this displays first 1000 rows

```
http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/jfzu-yy6n.json?$limit=1000&$offset=0
```

and this displays next 1000 rows

```
http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/jfzu-yy6n.json?$limit=1000&$offset=1000
```

3000 for the next 1000 and so on..

The problem is the next 1000 does not append itself to the previous 1000. Can I write a loop in jquery which would get all of them? Is this doable at all?

Answer (score 1):

just fetch your data , then use append().

however if you want to fetch your data once , then yes it is doable , and you can store data in an array , and append them upon request.

Comment: it takes sometime to respond though.

Comment: you may find this helpful :http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson

Comment: These are actually all pretty helpful. Thanks for the direction